# Configuration of Apache Ignite

Tags: ignite, web-console

to configure apache ignite, is there any web UI available?
I am not familiar with Java and it is a bit challenging to update the config files correctly.

Comment: There is no Web console. What kind of config you want to do?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to touch anything manually, you can check [GridGain Nebula](https://www.gridgain.com/products/gridgain-nebula). Free credits should be enough for your experiments.

I don't think there is something else available that allows you to setup and configure Apache Ignite without touching any code or config files.

After all, it's not that hard, there are a lot of docs available and for the first usage it's totally fine to go with the default configuration embedded. Just start with [this](https://ignite.apache.org/docs/latest/quick-start/java) guide; you can select your favorite programming language as well.